# What is the alternative for text.properties in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for a way to move all the text strings to a separate file. This will help with making making international version.

It should work like `hello_world.py`

```
print(hello_statement)
```

and `text.properties`:

```
hello_statement=Hello world
```

What is the right way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use additional libraries then this would work.

`text.properties`:

```
hello_statement=Hello world
```

Code:

```py
# open the file
with open("text.properties") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

source_dict = {}

# parse the file
for line in data:
    k, v = line.split("=")
    source_dict[k] = v

# print function
def print_from_file(statement):
    print(source_dict[statement])

# use print function
print_from_file("hello_statement")
```

However, @tomerikoo's comment with the `import` statement looks most elegant :)

Comment: Why manually implement something that is already implemented in a built-in library covering many edge-cases and pitfalls (i.e. `configparser` given in another answer)? For example, your code will not work if the user accidentally adds a space around the `=` sign...

Comment: Good point and I agree with you. However, the OP may or may not want to use additional library. I guess this is where my qualifying statement comes in: _If you don't want to use additional libraries_ .

Comment: But.... it's a built-in library. It's not like it requires installation...

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `.py` files for the different languages. For example, you can have:

**english.py**:

```
hello_statement = "Hello World"
```

and **spanish.py**:

```
hello_statement = "Hola Mundo"
```

And now you can import the matching file according to the language:

```
lang = "es"
if lang == "en":
    from english import *
elif lang == "es":
    from spanish import *
else:
    raise ValueError("Unsupported language:", lang)

print(hello_statement)
```